# How to get a list of users who has logged on to a remote computer?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access

I'm using a remote computer with admin rights. But looks like that someone has logged on this remote computer while I'm not logged and disturbed my running work.

Question: How to know who has logged on this computer for the last day for example?

PS: My computer and the remote one are both win 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy thing you could do is open `Event Viewer` and view the `Security` logs, which is found under the `Windows Logs` folder. If you organize the events by `Event ID` and look for `Event ID #4624`, which the task category for that event is `Logon`.

This will give you the account name of who logged in, and what the time/date was.

Here is an example of my event audit from when I logged back onto my computer earlier. [image]

Comment: I find filtering on eventID 4624 to be the best way to extract this information from the Security log.

Comment: As a side note to my answer, when filtering by event ID the times are no longer in chronological order by time. You could either choose to `Filter Current Log...` and specify what you want, or you could organize it by `Date and Time` then look for the correct ID. Assuming you have a general time frame of when this happened, sorting by `Date and Time` may be the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can I tell from which IP address he has logged? Because actually me and my team members all have the administrator account. So when I look at "Account Name", it just gives me "Administrator" which doesn't help.

Comment: @KhaledMaged as long as you guys all have a different computer, you can tell which computer it is by checking the computer name in the log. The computer name is the field that says `Computer`. I updated the image and circled the computer name field in blue.

Comment: @DrZoo But this field gives me the name of the remote computer in all cases. Even in the cases where I logged. Only the name of the remote computer itself. I know this may be weird, but that's what I have in front of me.

Comment: @KhaledMaged Another thing you could try is again going to Event Viewer and look under `Application and Services` logs. Then look under the `RemoteApp and Desktop Connections` folder and try the `TerminalServices-LocalConnectionManager`, `TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager` folders. Hopefully one of those have valuable information that you could use.