# Script to get a list of users allowed to connect computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, active-directory

I would like to inventory the users and groups that are allowed to connect to a computer (interactively or remotely). The computer can be either in a workgroup or in an active directory but primarily in an active directory.
If a group has access, I would also like to know which users are members of that group so that I can determine if the user has access granted directly or thanks to a role.

I would like to do it using PowerShell and remotely but I don't know from where to start.

NB:
Part of the solution can be found [here (who has logged on?)](https://superuser.com/questions/989835/how-to-get-a-list-of-users-who-has-logged-on-to-a-remote-computer)

Comment: Sure, it's (to me) an indication to see if the ones who have access have recently used their account.

Comment: there's a `logonworkstations` property foreach user in `get-aduser`. that should be your starting point.

Comment: It's not clear if you want a list of users/groups that CAN connect or user/groups that HAVE connected? If it's the former then group policy RSOP would help. Defaults here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221980%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

Comment: Hi smwk, it's the first one that I want... As the server OS is not on my charge but the RDBMS is, I want to know who possibly can access to it... Once I have the answer to who can connect, I may be interested by the when they connect...

Comment: It doesn't look easy to do with Powershell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934156/setting-log-on-as-a-service-and-allow-logon-locally-with-adsi . If it's just one server then use group policy RSOP, this can be done remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Default groups that can logon locally on a server:

- Administrators
- Backup Operators
- Users

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221980%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

Doing it with PowerShell is not easy, a few options listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934156/setting-log-on-as-a-service-and-allow-logon-locally-with-adsi